# unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ; in echo PHP

Tags: php

I'm keeping get this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in
```

on the following line...

```
echo '<li><div>'$caption'<a href='.($portfolio_url).'><img height='$src[2]' width='$src[1]' src='$src[0]' alt='$alt' /></a></div></li>';
```

I'm newbie in PHP and wrote this line with tutorial. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about string concatenation

Comment: ^ You are missing `.` in between your strings and variables.  So `'<div>'.$caption.'<a>'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate properly:

```
echo '<li><div>' . $caption . '<a href='.($portfolio_url).'><img height=' . $src[2] . ' width=' . $src[1] . ' src=' . $src[0] . ' alt='$alt' /></a></div></li>';
                 ^          ^
```

That is, always use the syntax:

```
echo 'text ' . $variable . ' more text';
```

So that you get (printed in multiple lines to make it more clear):

```
echo '<li><div>' . $caption . '<a hr ...
  .... ef=' . $portfolio_url . '><img
  .... height=' . $src[2] . ' width=' . $src[1] . ' src=' . $src[0] . ' 
  .... alt=' . $alt. ' /></a></div></li>';
```

Comment: I missed some dots, cross check that all of the variables are properly written as `text ' . $var . ' text';`